# Plone comments from anonymous

Tags: comments, plone

My plone server working under plone 4.3.2

At site#1 I enable discussion at control panel. Then anonymous user input comments at site with filled field "Name", comment posted with Name "Anonymous", but not "Name".

At another site#2 on this Plone server all OK - field "Name" of comment publishing at site.

I tested this with product plone.app.discussion version 2.2.8 and 2.2.10.
In ZMI in folder portal_scins/custom is records folder_listing, folder_tabular_view, logo.png, main_template, public.css.
If I editing file comments.pt in folder .../plone.app.discussion-2.2.8-py2.7.egg/.../browser/ for sample line 74 from 'says:' to 'says_:' publishing at site not changing.
But at site#2 publishing at site changing: writing 'says_:'

Earlier I install product quintagroup.plonecomments, but now it is deleted.Early all worked OK without activate quintagroup.plonecomments.

Comment: It could be something else overriding the comments viewlet. Install plone.app.debugtoolbar and try to figure out what is happening.